# Seo friendly Accordion menu

Tags: asp.net, accordion, seo

currently i use the accordion menu provided by the asp.net toolkit.

The problem is that it is not Seo friendly. So what i am looking for is an accordion menu with the following characteristics.

1) Seo friendliness

2) Preserving of the selected index, on post-backs.

3) Small in k bytes

4) Free of charge

Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: what is un-seo-friendly in that?

Comment: Only the expanded menu is friendly and i suppose bots do not click

Comment: bots can read the collapsed element as well, they are just marked as style="disply:none" don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Asp.Net Accordion is obviously SEO friendly but it lot's more depends on how you use it, I generally use BulletedList inside the accordion panes to dynamically bind the related links.

and they work great for me, they are user friendly(If designed properly), and also SEO friendly as well.

(2) This post on [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/1164172/1932163.aspx) can help you answer your postback related problems.

(3) this is not too good but not too bad (I think)

(4) this is free and even open source you can use/change source code

So if you want another option only because of SEO Friendliness, then don't do that, another option is [jQuery UI accordion](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/)